# inner array sorting in smarty

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, smarty

**test1.php**

```
 <?php
    include ("includes/application_top.inc.php");
     $smarty->assign('user', array(
                                 array('firstname' => 'john',
                                       'lastname' => 'aaa',
                                        'numbers'=>array(21,20,55,44)),
                                 array('firstname' => 'jack',
                                       'lastname' => 'zzz',
                                       'numbers'=>array(23,21,76,34)),
                                array('firstname' => 'jill',
                                      'lastname' => 'ddd',
                                      'numbers'=>array(43,23,54,76)),
                                ));
     $smarty->display('test1.tpl');
    ?>
```

**test1.tpl**

```
<table>
 {foreach item=item key=key from=$user|@sortby:"numbers"} 
 {$item.firstname} <br/>
 {$item.lastname} <br/>
 {$item.numbers} <br/>
 {/foreach}
</table>
```

**Question**

I want result as sorted numbers. When i m performing sorting by firstname or lastname it is working fine. but only problem with array inside array.

**Any idea how to do inner array sorting in smarty.**

Comment: How do you want to sort records by this numbers? What output is required?

Comment: do you want to sort the values inside the array numbers? `array(21,20,55,44)` for example?

Comment: it should be like firstname ... lastname ... test 20,21,44,55 likewise. Is it possible in smarty?

Comment: and why don't you sort numbers in php?

Comment: Don't try to put business login into smarty. Sort them in your backend and pass the sanitized (= sorted) array to smarty.

Answer (score 1):

You should do sorting in PHP (or if you get data from database just proper order by in query).

Solution with sorting in PHP below:

PHP:

```
  $arr1 = array(21,20,55,44);
  $arr2 = array(23,21,76,34);
  $arr3 = array(43,23,54,76);
  sort($arr1);
  sort($arr2);
  sort($arr3);
          $smarty->assign('user', array(
                             array('firstname' => 'john',
                                   'lastname' => 'aaa',
                                    'numbers'=> $arr1),
                             array('firstname' => 'jack',
                                   'lastname' => 'zzz',
                                   'numbers'=> $arr2),
                            array('firstname' => 'jill',
                                  'lastname' => 'ddd',
                                  'numbers'=>$arr3),
                                    ));
```

Smarty:

```
<table>
 {foreach item=item key=key from=$user} 
 {$item.firstname} <br/>
 {$item.lastname} <br/>
     {foreach $item.numbers as $number} 
     {$number} 
     {/foreach}
 <br/>
 {/foreach}
</table>
```

In my opinion there is no point at all to do complex operation in template engine. Data should be prepared by PHP and Smarty should just display them.

Comment: I support this approach; business logic is no template thing!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do it like this:

```
<table>
 {foreach item=item key=key from=$user}
 {$item.firstname} <br/>
 {$item.lastname} <br/>
 {if $item.numbers|@sort eq 1}{/if}
     {foreach $item.numbers as $number}
     {$number},
     {/foreach} <br/>
 {/foreach}
</table>
```

To explain the if:
If you do `{$item.numbers|@sort}` it will echo `1` because that is the output of sort. But if you put it inside an if, the output is not shown on the page, but the function is runned.

The sortby thing is a plugin, which works different than you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Veda.
It will also work when loop is inside "if" correctly without echoing `1`:

```
<table>
 {foreach item=item key=key from=$user}
 {$item.firstname} <br/>
 {$item.lastname} <br/>
     {if $item.numbers|@sort eq 1}
         {foreach $item.numbers as $number}
         {$number},
         {/foreach}
     {/if}
 <br/>
 {/foreach}
</table>
```